# Trim spaces from values in MySQL table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, trim

I want to update all the values in a table by trimming all the leading and trailing spaces. I have tried the following queries but neither worked.

I know that it is possible to use TRIM with SELECT, but how can I use it with UPDATE?

```
UPDATES teams SET name = TRIM(name)
UPDATES teams SET name = TRIM(LEADING ' ' TRAILING ' ' FROM name)
```

Comment: it works for me...i just tried it out.  
"update Users set firstname=trim(firstname);"

Comment: Yeap, I used `UPDATES` instead of `UPDATE`. Some times I'm blind...

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You do not have to `SELECT`.

Try this -

```
UPDATE teams SET name = TRIM(name)
WHERE 1 = 1;
```

Comment: It worked, but it's not that. I was stupid. I used `UPDATES` instead of `UPDATE`. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 17):

```
UPDATE teams SET name = TRIM(name)
```

That should work, it is semantically correct for MySQL.

Answer (score 8):

If field contain new line character then

```
UPDATE Tablename SET colname= TRIM(TRAILING '\r' FROM colname)
```

Comment: UPDATE Tablename SET colname= TRIM(TRAILING '\n' FROM colname)   worked for me.

Comment: /n or /r both are special characters

Comment: Yes, I got idea from your answer.. Thanks.. 

Answer (score 1):

This one solves a weird problem I was having when the TRIM option does not work:

```
UPDATE
    teams
SET
    name    = TRIM(BOTH UNHEX('C2A0') FROM name)
```

Comment: I ran into this exact scenario after scraping data from a web page. Nice job!